# CoreML : "Unexpected error processing model" error sometimes occurring

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

**Context:**
I'm using a custom CoreML model made by a datascientist.
The model is a pipeline that uses Apple `SoundAnalysisPreprocessing` model as it's first model. `SoundAnalysisPreprocessing` model is followed by a custom model that contains different convolution layers and a softmax.

**Issue:**
When launching a prediction, I sometimes get `Unexpected error processing model`. With the exact same input, I sometimes get a correct result and sometimes I get this error.

**Question:** I have no clue what to do with this error. Is it a memory problem with input being badly allocated ? Is it a problem with the model itself ?
Do you have any idea what I could do to understand what is happening ?

**Complete error log:**

```
[DSPGraph] throwing DSPGraph::Exception with backtrace:
0       0x7fff2bcf5df9  DSPGraph::Graph::processMultiple(DSPGraph::GraphIOData*, DSPGraph::GraphIOData*) + 249
1       0x7fff2bc3b570  processThroughGraph(id<MLFeatureProvider>, MLMultiArrayConstraint*, MLMultiArray*, NSString*, DSPGraph::Graph&, std::__1::vector<float, DSPGraph::Graph&::allocator<float> >&, void (DSPGraph::Graph, NSString*::GraphIOData&) block_pointer, NSError* __autoreleasing*) + 979
2       0x7fff2bc3c573  -[SNDSPGraphCustomModel predictionFromFeatures:options:error:] + 195
3       0x7fff2bc3ca49  -[_SNVGGishFrontEndProcessingCustomModel predictionFromFeatures:options:error:] + 98
4       0x7fff2496ac30  -[MLAppleSoundAnalysisPreprocessing predictionFromFeatures:options:error:] + 132
5       0x7fff248d345c  -[MLPipeline predictionFromFeatures:options:error:] + 178
6       0x7fff24923f76  -[MLModel predictionFromFeatures:error:] + 92
7          0x104b89a68  $s10TestCoreML17AudioFileAnalyzerC019previsionWithManualD3Cut33_1966162A0510E69792A8D979B37CC177LL3for10completiony10Foundation3URLV_ySo12MLMultiArrayCSgXEtF + 5992
8          0x104b87850  $s10TestCoreML17AudioFileAnalyzerC05startF03for10completiony10Foundation3URLV_yyXEtF + 80
9          0x104bb360c  $s10TestCoreML23ClassificationViewModelC14startRecognize4word8mockData11resultBlock06finishM0ySS_SbySb_SaySo16SNClassificationCGSgtcSgyyctF + 3436
10         0x104bad21c  $s10TestCoreML18ReadViewControllerC010collectionE0_15didSelectItemAtySo012UICollectionE0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtFyycfU_ + 220
11         0x104b923fd  $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 45
12         0x104f79d64  _dispatch_client_callout + 8
13         0x104f7c6d6  _dispatch_continuation_pop + 552
14         0x104f8fa8f  _dispatch_source_invoke + 2205
15         0x104f87c53  _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1043
[truncated?]
2019-10-30 20:33:04.209693+0100 TestCoreML[5024:191792] [] Caught graph exception 1718775073 !mrf fromBytePos (0) + numBytesToCopy (61440) > mABL->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize (2112) in /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Listen_Sim/Listen-35/CoreAudioUtility/Source/CADSP/DSPGraph/DSPGraph_Utils.cpp:742
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to update some of the libs in your code. Based on this GitHub related to your error.

[Github](https://github.com/alfredh/baresip/issues/784)

graph exception 1718775073 is the key.

In the forum they said this was the fix, because of a weird difference in between incoming call vs outgoing call variables.

```
if (-0.01f <= hw_srate || hw_srate >= 0.1.f)
{
fmt.mSampleRate = prm->state;
fat->sample_rate = 1.0f;
}
```

Comment: The only lib related to audio code I have is CoreML. And we are on iOS12 already.
Thx for the github link but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Try using print on the size of objects in the file at the bottom of the error.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this you have to manually move the model file into the app directory and then add it to xcode - it seems to be a bug in Xcode putting the model that is stored in another directory into the app package